# axios.get() returns undefined response

Tags: ajax, rest, xmlhttprequest, axios, aurelia

I'm using axios in an aurelia project and following their docs, I've set up a basic get request like so

```
import Axios from '../../node_modules/axios/index';

export class testService {
  constructor() {
    this.axios = new Axios({
      withCredentials: false,
      headers:{
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    });
  }

  test() {
    this.axios.get('/items')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
      });
  }
}
```

I have an api server running at '`http://localhost:3000/items`' and hitting that url in Chrome and Postman, I can get valid JSON responses. However, running the above code (ie. calling the `test()` method from), the response logged is `undefined`.

I have looked at other answers to similar problems, but none of them have worked for me so far. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to mistake in `new Axios({ ...config ... })` signature. According to [their doc](https://github.com/axios/axios), you need `.create` method to create axios instance:

```
this.axios = Axios.create({
  withCredentials: false,
  headers:{
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did look at [their docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) but seems like they only explain the `create` part further down.

Comment: btw, you can do `import Axios from 'axios';` instead of `import Axios from '../../node_modules/axios/index';`

Comment: Yep, this was just VS code's autofill doing it's thing. Thanks.